# ASP.NET MVC Populating dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, drop-down-menu

I've been trying to populate a dropdownlist for a while now and would appreciate some help. I have my model and viewmodel and my trying to populate the Dropdownlist and send it to the view so a user can choose a cartype and click submit.

```
public class Cars
{
    public int CarId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class CarViewModel
{
    public int SelectedCarId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CarTypes;

}

public ActionResult FillDropDown()
{
     var model = new ViewModel();
     model.CarTypes = (from s in context.CarTypes
                      select new SelectListItem()
                      {
                         Text = s.Name,
                         Value = SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)s.Id).Trim(),
                      }).ToList<SelectListItem>();

    return View(model);
}
```

So I would like some help how to render this in the view. I tried the following but I get a nullreference exception.

```
@Html.BeginForm("FillDropDownList","Home", FormMethod.Post,null)
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedCarId, Model.CarTypes);
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
}
```

Comment: Use 'CarViewModel' instead of 'ViewModel' in your action result.

Comment: Where do you get the exception? Where does `context` come from? Is it `null`? Is `Model.CarTypes` or even `Model` `null`?

Comment: I can see that it's populated with the right data when I send it to the view: return View(model). But then at line: @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedCarId, Model.CarTypes); I get a nullreference exception saying Model.CarTypes is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use CarViewModel instead of ViewModel.

```
public ActionResult FillDropDown()
{
   var model = new CarViewModel(); //CarViewModel instead of ViewModel
   model.CarTypes = (from s in context.CarTypes
                     select new SelectListItem()
                     {
                        Text = s.Name,
                        Value = SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)s.Id).Trim(),
                     }).ToList<SelectListItem>();

   return View(model);
}
```

---

**EDIT:**

Change your IEnumerable property in CarViewModel into SelectList

```
public class CarViewModel
{
    public int SelectedCarId { get; set; }
    public SelectList CarTypes;
}
```

Make sure the SelectListItem is not null, in the FillDropDown() method.

Comment: thx! It's actually this line that's not working: @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedCarId, Model.CarTypes); I want to post back the selectedCarId. The model is populated with the right data.